# How to use param here in this code of C# with/without regex

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 
class GFG
{
    static String remVowel(String str)
    {
        str = Regex.Replace(str, "[aeiouAEIOU]", "");
        return str;
    }
     
    // Driver code
    public static void Main()
    {
        String str = "Good morning";    
        Console.WriteLine(remVowel(str));
    }
}
```

Comment: question unclear, could you explain what are you trying to achieve? is it removing vowels without using regex?

Comment: i want to remove vowels using param fuction

Comment: it  should accept string as param

Comment: you want the `"[aeiouAEIOU]"` part parameterized? could you give example parameter input?

Comment: yes , the string should be given as param

Comment: Maybe you want `void RemVowel(ref string str)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Main()
    {
         String str = "Good morning"; 
         Console.WriteLine(remVowel(str,"[aeiouAEIOU]"));
    }
    
    static String remVowel(String str, string _regex)
    {
        str = Regex.Replace(str, _regex, "");
        return str;
    }
```